# Why is cshtml extension required?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I've been using MVC for 2 years and in all this time I never had to use the `.cshtml' extension when referring to views. Now I upgraded to RC2 and started getting "View not found errors". Apart from the pain of adding the extension I now have a lot of code that does not contain the extension.

Is there a way to remove the need for this extension?

PS: I don't know what happened when moving to RC2 but I did not upgrade my project instead created a new one and copied all classes, controllers and views from the old one and fixed the namespaces afterwards.

Comment: I upgraded some major projects from rc1 to rc2 and my views still work without any need for .cshtml. must be something specific to your app

Comment: @JoeAudette it is also wierd that most still work without extension. The problem seems to be for partials.

Comment: works for me for partials without that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ron C [wrote above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700385/why-is-cshtml-extension-required/37709636#answer-37703874), its not about `ViewResult` or `PartialViewResult`, its about missing the filename extension ".cshtml", when you "viewName" parameter has a relative path value.

That is how the `RazorViewEngine` (default implementation of `IRazorViewEngine`) is working in RC2. You can view the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorViewEngine.cs).

A solution could be to override the View and PartialView methods of a `BaseController` to automatically append ".cshtml" when needed.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [NonAction]
    public override ViewResult View(string viewName, object model)
    {
        return base.View(AppendRazorFileExtensionIfNeeded(viewName), model);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public override PartialViewResult PartialView(string viewName, object model)
    {
        return base.PartialView(AppendRazorFileExtensionIfNeeded(viewName), model);
    }

    private string AppendRazorFileExtensionIfNeeded(string viewName)
    {
        // If viewname is not empty or null
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            // If viewname does have a relative path
            if (viewName[0] == '~' || viewName[0] == '/')
            {
                // If viewname does not have a ".cshtml" extension
                if (!viewName.EndsWith(".cshtml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    viewName = string.Concat(viewName, ".cshtml");
                }
            }
        }

        return viewName;
    }
}
```

Comment: tmg - that's sweet you were able to provide a link to my response.  How is that done?

Comment: @RonC I inspected the id of the element of your answer and I added it as hashtag

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed is that the .cshtml is not required if only the view name is returned, for example:

```
return View("hello-world");
```

But it is required if the location of the view is also specified, for example:

```
return View("/Views/Universe/hello-world.cshtml");
```

Comment: I also noticed that as well.